# React-router: Pass props in Link and map match data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to figure out what I'm not doing well.

I have a shops object which is a database with different shop inside.
I want to render each shop's information in their own page thanks to react-router.

I already try many way to render my details.

The error that always come back its that I can read props, or state of undefined in my shopDetails component. When I want to console log my location element, it is shown as undefined but when I go to my react developer tool I can see my shops data right stored in my shopDetails props.location...

I really don't understand how to render the good data. I open all other subject without understanding how to deal with my problem.

If you could help on this, it would be amazing. Thanks for your time.

App.js

```
 render() {
    return (
      <Router>
          <HeaderFilters
            wrapperHeaderFunction={this.wrapperHeaderFunction}
            zip_code={this.state.zip_code}
            handleChanges={this.handleChanges}
            isClicked={this.isClicked}
            filterClick={this.filterClick}
            selectedOption={this.state.selectedOption}
            moreFilterClick={this.moreFilterClick}
            filteredResults={this.state.filteredResults}
            rating={this.state.rating}
            startDate={this.state.startDate} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null,
            startDateId="your_unique_start_date_id" // PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            endDate={this.state.endDate} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null,
            endDateId="your_unique_end_date_id" // PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            onDatesChange={({ startDate, endDate }) =>
              this.setState({ startDate, endDate })
            } // PropTypes.func.isRequired,
            focusedInput={this.state.focusedInput} // PropTypes.oneOf([START_DATE, END_DATE]) or null,
            onFocusChange={focusedInput => this.setState({ focusedInput })} // PropTypes.func.isRequired,
          />

          {this.state.isMoreFiltersRequired ? (
            <MoreFilters
              handleChanges={this.handleChanges}
              isClicked={this.isClicked}
              filterClick={this.filterClick}
              moreFilterClick={this.moreFilterClick}
              filteredResults={this.state.filteredResults}
              rating={this.state.rating}
            />
          ) : null}
          <div>
            {this.state.login ? <Spinner animation="border" size="xl" /> : null}
          </div>


          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/"
              render={() => (
                <ShopPreview
                  loading={this.state.loading}
                  shops={this.state.shops}
                  filteredResults={this.state.filteredResults}
                  rating={this.state.rating}
                />
              )}
            />

            <Route
              path="/search"
              render={() => (
                <ShopSearch
                  loading={this.state.loading}
                  shops={this.state.shops}
                  filteredResults={this.state.filteredResults}
                  rating={this.state.rating}
                />
              )}
            />

            <Route
              path={`/shopDetail/:id`}
              render={routeProps => (
                <ShopDetails {...routeProps} shops={this.state.shops} />
              )}
            />
          </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Shops.js (the component which renders the shop list)

```
 render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <ListGroup>
          {this.props.shops.map((detail, index) => (
            <ListGroup.Item key="index">
              <Row>
                <Col>
                  <Image
                    alt=""
                    src={detail.imgURL}
                    width={150}
                    height={150}
                    rounded
                  />
                </Col>
                <Col>
                  <h3 className="shop_title">{detail.nom}</h3>
                  <StarRatings
                    rating={this.props.rating}
                    starRatedColor="#DAA520"
                    changeRating={this.changeRating}
                    numberOfStars={5}
                    starDimension="15px"
                    name="rating"
                    starSpacing="2px"
                  />
                  <p id="resume">{detail.resume}</p>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                  <Row>
                    {detail.startPrice === ""
                      ? "Sur devis"
                      : "A partir de " + detail.startPrice + " €"}
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                    {/* Make route with id, with key= detail.id */}
                    <Link
                      to={{
                        pathname: "/shopDetail/" + detail.id,
                        state: {shops : this.props.shops}
                      }}
                    >
                      <Button
                        className="detailButton"
                        key={detail.id}
                        variant="primary"
                        onClick={this.props.filterClick}
                      >
                        Détails
                      </Button>
                    </Link>
                  </Row>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </ListGroup.Item>
          ))}
        </ListGroup>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default Shops;
```

ShopDetails.js (the component which renders the shop details according to its URL id)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class ShopDetails extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.setState({
      })
    }
  render() { 
     
      console.log("Props shops: " ,this.props.shops)
      const id = window.location.pathname.replace("/shopDetail/", "");
      const data = this.props.shops
      const location = this.props.location
      console.log("Location:", location)
      const shop = data.find(s => s.id === id)
      
      return (
  <div>
    <h1>{shop.id}</h1>
    <h3>{shop.nom}</h3>
    <p>{shop.website}</p>
  </div>
)    
}}
 
export default ShopDetails
```

For now, I'm just allow to render the id, but I can't access to my elements "shops" in my state which stock my shop data to map on each component.

edit:
[SCREENSHOT CONSOLE.LOG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaIhL.png)

edit2:

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react'
    
    class ShopDetails extends Component {
        constructor(props){
          super(props)
          this.setState({
            shop:{}
          })
        }
      render() { 
         
          console.log("Props shops: " ,this.props.shops)
          const id = window.location.pathname.replace("/shopDetail/", "");
          console.log("id: ", id)
          const data = this.props.shops
          console.log("data: ", data)
          const location = this.props.location.state
          console.log("Location:", location)
          const shop = data.find(s => s.id === id)
          
          return (
      <div>
      
      </div>
    )    
    }}
     
    export default ShopDetails
```

Edit3

[Screen log object developed1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1o7n.png)
Edit3

[Screen log object developed2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm5hO.png)
Edit3

[Screen log object developed3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRBPY.png)

Edit 4:

const shop, can finally be render something in console.log

Problem was about a triple = in my const shop = data.find(s => s.id == id)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class ShopDetails extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.setState({
        shop:{}
      })
    }
  render() { 
     
      console.log("Props shops: " ,this.props.shops)
      const id = window.location.pathname.replace("/shopDetail/", "");
      console.log("id: ", id)
      const data = this.props.shops
      console.log("data: ", data)
      const shop = data.find(s => s.id == id)
      console.log("shop: ", shop)
      console.log("this.props.match.params.id: ", this.props.match.params.id)
      
      return (
  <div>
     {shop.map((detail, index) => (
       <div key={index}>
         <h1>{detail.nom}</h1>
       </div>

     ))}
    <p>{data.id}</p>
  
  </div>
)    
}}
 
export default ShopDetails
```

Now I have to return my data stored in my shop const, see below the link of the console.log(shop) since the edit 4

[screenshot edit4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gvfQ.png)

Comment: Can you create a codepen to show is, how the data is stored and passed around ?

Comment: What do you want my codepen show as component exactly ? I will do it

Comment: Can you show us the console.log of both the id and this.props.shop in detail?

Comment: I have edited my post with the screen of my console.log if that could help

Comment: Can your expand the objects and also log this.props.match.params.id?

Comment: Yep sir its done

Comment: Ok it looks good so far. Can you log each object in find like this find(s => {console.log(s,id), return s.id===id}?

Comment: edit with last change ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the == instead of === because the id of your shop is a number and the id from your url is a string. If you cast the id from your url to number, it should also work with ===. To render your shop data, after you find it, should not be done with map since you cannot access the object keys with it. You should just render it with shop.nom etc. Hope this helps. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

But when I try to render it with {shop.nom}, I have an error return saying TypeError: Cannot read property 'nom' of undefined 
What is weird because I have an object with this "nom" key inside as you can see in my last screen shot edit

Comment: I think that you have to provide a codepen so that we can take a look at the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, solve my problem !

So first I had this problem with my === operator as well explain Domino987 previously.

Then if I couldn't render my {shop.nom} element even if I could see my shop element in my props.

[click to see my  console.log("const shop = data.find(...): ", shop);](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLZ9q.png)

It is because at the moment the component renders, there is not value inside shop.
We can know that by looking at the 'i' icon in my dev tools.

So I had 2 options:

You have 2 options:

Put all my information in state, not like shop={}, but like bornePhoto, cabinePhoto, helio, booth… etc, then it first renders with empty information, and then when the information arrives, it updates the state and it will shown.

Conditional render. Example:

```
if (!shop.nom){
    return null
} else {
    return <h1>{shop.nom}<h1/>
}
```

OR :

```
{Boolean(shop.nom) ? <h1>{shop.nom}<h1/> : null}
```

I  used ternary method with the following code:

```
class ShopDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {  }
  }
  render() { 
    console.log("Props shops: ", this.props.shops);
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;
    console.log("id: ", id);
    const data = this.props.shops || {};
    console.log("data: ", data);
    const shop = data.find(s => s.id == id);
    console.log("const shop = data.find(...): ", shop);

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Row>
          <Col>
            {shop ? (
              <Image
                alt=""
                src={shop.imgURL}
                width={150}
                height={150}
                rounded
              />
            ) : null}
          </Col>
          <Col  >
           {shop ? <h1>{shop.nom}</h1> : null}
          {shop ? <h2>A partir de {shop.startPrice} €</h2> : null}
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row >
          <Col >
            <h3>Site internet:</h3>
           {shop ? <p>{shop.website}</p> : null}
          </Col>
          <Col >
            <h3>Services</h3>
            <p>Rappel des services</p>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row >
          <Col>
            <h4>Présentation</h4>
            {shop ? <p>{shop.resume}</p> : null}
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ShopDetails;
```

That solve my problem, and I could finally render my elements.

If that could help someone, I will be glad !

Thanks to all the community for helping me in my project !